# How to set a Initial file name in a SaveFileDialog?

Tags: c#

I created a script for a save-file-dialog to save a file. It has the Initial location set to the desktop. Now my question is, how do i set an initial "name" for the file in the dialog?

Here's my code:

```
private SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();

    private void Information(string Basic, string nameoffile, string program)
    {

        if (doingsomething) return;

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"Please select where you would like to store the file)"

        save.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

If there is an answer for this, please point where I can find it. Because i don't know the exact keyword.

Comment: You can use `FileName` property of SaveFileDialog. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_FileName

Answer (score 0):

You can asssign default name like 
`save.FileName="File1";`